# How to run background task in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am looking for a solution to excute a background task with schedule or timer. My task will run each 5 minutes or 10 minutes for update user status (health data, location tracking, etc...) when the app is in the background (maybe not terminate). I have found some libs, but It's not good with me:

- `Workmanager`: I get error `MissingPluginException` when excute the function of other lib in the callback method. This issue by isolate.
- `Background_fetch`: I cannot set the time interval less than 15 minutes for run the task.

If do not any solution I think, I need to write own background task plugin to use.

Have any suggest to solve my issue?.